# please Correct For Loop Design

Tags: java

```
class aaaaa
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      for (int k = 10; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int j = 100; j >=10; j=j-10) {
        System.out.print(j);
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

i want it like that output:

```
100 90 80 70 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
90 90 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
40 30 20 10 
-----------------
30 20 10
-----------------
20 10
-----------------
10
-----------------
```

but it's always be like:

```
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
100908070605040302010
-----------------
```

Comment: Welcome to _Programmers_. Questions about why specific code does not work are [off topic on this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/129632#129632).

Comment: Code reviews are off topic. Anyway, in your second inner loop you should not assign `j = 100` but `j = 100 - (10 * i)` (Also you example output seems to have some errors)

Answer (score 1):

Look at my example code. It does exactly what you want to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 10 - i; j > 0; j = j--)
        {
            System.out.print(j * 10);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first nested `for` loop is never executed. The outer for loop will set `i` to at most 10. The condition `k < i` will never be true for the first iteration, so it will never run.

So remove this:

```
for (int k = 10; k < i; k++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Your second nested `for` loop wil always have the same output. The conditions are always the same no matter what. To have spaces between the numbers, you need to put `System.out.print(" ");` in this `for` loop.

You need to change the second loop to this:

```
for (int j = 100 - (10 * i); j > 10; j=j-10) {
    System.out.print(j);
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Note that we changed the starting index for `j` to `100 - (10 * i)`. This means that for every iteration of the outer loop, the largest number will be removed.

> In iteration 1, the first result is 100 - (10 * 0) = 100.
>
> In iteration 2, the first result is 100 - (10 * 1) = 90.
>
> In iteration 3, the first result is 100 - (10 * 2) = 80.
>
> ...
>
> In iteration 10, the first result is `100 - (10 * 9) = 10`.

The last result will always be `100 - (10 * 9) = 10`. (I have changed the condition from `j >= 10` to `j > 10`. Otherwise, the last result would be `100 - (10 * 10) = 0`.)

---

The final, working code:

```
class aaaaa
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 100 - (10 * i); j > 10; j=j-10) {
                System.out.print(j);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```